# GPU breakpoint not hit when using C++ AMP

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gpgpu, c++-amp

I've set the debugger type to `GPU only` and set a breakpoint on every line of an 8-line `parallel_for_each` lambda, including the line `parallel_for_each` statement, but it never gets hit.  I'm using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8 Pro.

What step do I need to take to make the breakpoint work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your application explicitly providing an accelerator/accelerator_view for the parallel_for_each? If so you need to ensure that when debugging you use the REF accelerator unless your GPU driver supports debugging.

```
    accelerator defaultAcc (accelerator::default_accelerator);
    accelerator_view defaultView = defaultAcc.default_view;

#ifndef _DEBUG
    std::vector<accelerator> allAccelerators = accelerator::get_all();
    allAccelerators.erase(std::remove_if(allAccelerators.begin(), allAccelerators.end(), 
        [](const accelerator& acc){ return (acc.is_emulated) || 
                            (acc.device_path == accelerator::cpu_accelerator);} ),
                 allAccelerators.end());

    if (allAccelerators.size() > 0)
        defaultView = allAccelerators[0].default_view;
#endif
```

Comment: Ade is correct, of course. If anyone runs into other issues with starting GPU debugging, please read this blog post which covers all isses (incl. the one Ade described): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/03/17/start-gpu-debugging-in-visual-studio-11.aspx